Is there a way to create a new project template from a project using CSOM for MS Project?
I was wondering if there is a way to create a new project template with a existing project that has been published via code using the Project Server CSOM?
I tried to search around the documentation and could not find anything that could possibly work. This is for MS Project 2016.
